# Windows Error: The window terminated unexpectedly (reason:'launch-failed',code:'18')

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

When I open VS Code, this error emerges. When I click on any button of the error window, VS Code closed and I can't open it again. What should I do to eliminate this issue?

My OS is Windows 10 and VS Code version is 1.76.0. I installed it from Microsoft Store.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system had an anti-ransomware installed, but after disabling it, the issue was resolved. It's possible that the anti-ransomware was locking VS Code.